# The html src attribute is not being rendered with the report

Tags: sql-server, image, reporting-services

i've a problem with my report server or the rdl template, the image controls are not displayed because src attribute is not setted.

[Report screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KLiv.jpg)

Watch the image please.

```
            <Image Name="imgFotos1">
              <Source>External</Source>
              <Value>=(Parameters!nombreServidorDocumentacion.Value + Fields!rutaFotografia.Value.ToString() + "/" + Fields!idFotografia.Value.ToString() + "." + Parameters!extensionImagen.Value).ToString().Replace(" ","%20")</Value>
              <MIMEType>image/jpeg</MIMEType>
              <Sizing>Fit</Sizing>
              <Left>0.67128cm</Left>
              <Height>10cm</Height>
              <Width>16cm</Width>
              <ToolTip>=(Parameters!nombreServidorDocumentacion.Value + Fields!rutaFotografia.Value.ToString() + "/" + Fields!idFotografia.Value.ToString() + "." + Parameters!extensionImagen.Value).ToString().Replace(" ","%20")</ToolTip>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Style>Solid</Style>
                </Border>
              </Style>
            </Image>
```

Comment: you need to give more information in order for anyone to help. maybe the actual RDL if possible?

Comment: Sorry, because i'm beginner here stackoverflow does not let me to publish my rdl document (too large) but i can tell you the report used to work, but the server owner makes some inaccesible updates to it.

Comment: well if you are pulling image from third part and they have changed your access then you need to find another place to pull the image.

How about you add the settings for just the image alone, you can load the RDL in notepad ++ and copy out just the XML for the image

Comment: Ready, each time i edit the question it recieve negative points o.o

Comment: So what does the URL for the image end up being?

Comment: is a jpg image of leonardo dicaprio that current exists and is public, if you check the image in the original post the toolTip fx is the same that the vaule fx.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your value is not being interpreted correctly. You need to make sure that your value starts with http://. If it does not, then the image will not render correctly. As you've blocked out that part of the tooltip in your referenced image, I can't see whether or not it is there. It must be a fully delimited html path. Please note, just because you can copy and paste the tooltip into your browser and get the image does not mean that SSRS properly recognized the URL, which is probably why it is coming out as blank.